# Angular 5 - Replace Value Using Array Filter

Tags: angular, typescript

How do you replace a value using an array filter? I have an array that contains something like this:

`this.detailsToDisplay = [{key: "key1", value: "value1"},{key: "key2", value: "value2"},{key: "key3", value: "value3"},{key: "key4", value: "value4"},]`

Then I try to replace the one in index 0 with the one from index 3 with this:

```
this.newValue1 = this.detailsToDisplay.filter(data => data.key === "key3");
            this.detailsToDisplay[0].value = this.newValue1[0].value;
```

While this works just fine, what if `[0]` is not constant? How do I dynamically assign the value from `key3` to `key1` without explicitly calling their array positions?

Answer (score 0):

I know you specifically asked about using `Array.filter` but it's not needed here:

```
this.detailsToDisplay.find(data => data.key === "key1").value = this.detailsToDisplay.find(data => data.key === "key3").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for both source and target.

```
this.source = this.detailsToDisplay.filter(data => data.key === "key3");
this.target = this.detailsToDisplay.filter(data => data.key === "key1");
if (this.source.length && this.target.length)   
  this.target[0].value = this.source[0].value;
```

Comment: `Array.filter` returns an array, not a single item.